# Boost Variant: how to get currently held type?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

As I understood all types of [boost.variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/variant.html) are parsed into real types (meaning as if boost `variant<int, string> a; a="bla-bla"` would after compilation turn into `string a; a="bla-bla"`) And so I wonder: how to get what type was put into boost variant?

What have I tried:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::function<double (double x)> func0;
    typedef boost::function<double (double x, double y)> func1;
    typedef boost::variant<int, func0, func1> variant_func;
    func1 fn = std::plus<double>();
    variant_func v(fn);
    std::cout << boost::get<func1>(v)(1.0, 1.0) << std::endl; // this works
    //std::cout << boost::get<v::type>(v)(1.0, 1.0) << std::endl; // this does not compile with many errors
    // std::cout << (v)(1.0, 1.0) << std::endl; // this fails with Error    1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

`v.which()` will return the 0-based index of the type of the object currently held.

When you are retrieving the object your code must use a static type (in order to satisfy the `get<T>` function template) to refer to an (effectively) dynamically typed object.

You need to either test for the type (using `which()` or `type()`) and branch accordingly or use a static visitor. No matter which way you choose, you have to explicitly state the static type that you want to retrieve and it has to match the dynamic type or an exception will be thrown.

One way around this problem is instead of using a variant type directly, use a class which contains a variant type internally and then defines any implicit conversion operators necessary to use the object with minimum fuss.

I have a project called [Dynamic C++](https://github.com/ferruccio/dynamic-cpp) which uses this technique.

Comment: Can it help getting  boost::get<T>(v)(1.0, 1.0) or (v)(1.0, 1.0) working?

Comment: No. You need to use the get<T>() syntax or static visitor to retrieve the contents of a variant.

Comment: Does Dynamic C++  support any types (say for example  int(*)(std::string, int) type)?

Comment: No, it has a fixed set of types. But it's pretty simple, although tedious, to add new types. Especially if you want to allow operations between types.

Comment: +1 for dynamic C++, it isn't my thing but I gave it a look and it looks very clean. Well done!

Answer (score 18):

`boost.variant` has a [`.type()` function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#id1752388-bb) which can return the typeid of the active type, provided you've enabled RTTI.

You could also define a static visitor to perform actions depending on the type of content of the variant, e.g.

```
struct SomeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    double operator()(const func0& f0) const { return f0(1.0); }
    double operator()(const func1& f1) const { return f1(1.0, 1.0); }
    double operator()(int integer) const { return integer; }
};
...
std::cout << boost::apply_visitor(SomeVisitor(), v) << std::endl;
```

Comment: so it shall be possible to call `  boost::get<v.type()>(v)(1.0, 1.0)` if RTTI is on?

Comment: @myWallJSON: No, because the template argument must be a type, known at compile time, not a run-time `typeid` object.

Comment: so  may be any sorts of casting like `((v.type()) v)(1.0, 1.0)` ?

Comment: @myWallJSON: The stored value is best accessed with a static_visitor as shown above. If you use `get`, then it means that you know statically which type is currently stored, or you try to get the value as a type and then deal with the NULL pointer or exception. - RTTI results cannot be used for any compile-time things (such as casts). A typeid is an object containing run-time description of a type, it does not yield a typename that can be used at compile-time.

Comment: @myWallJSON: You can do `boost::get<X>(variant)(1.0, 1.0);` but you better wrap it in a try block, because if `variant` is not storing an object of type `X`, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: @UncleBens: Or use `boost::get<X>(&variant)` and then null-check the result.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following that both result in std::type_info objects:

- the type() member function of boost::variant,
- the C++ operator typeid() that can be applied to any type or typed expression,

together with the member function std::type_info::operator==, to check which type the boost::variant is currently storing. For example,

```
boost::variant<int, bool, std::string> container;
container = "Hello world";

if (container.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
    std::cout << "Found a string: " << boost::get<std::string>(container);
}
else if (container.type() == typeid(int)) {
    std::cout << "Found an int: " << boost::get<int>(container);
}
```

Comment: Nope! This will crash and burn if a vector has been included in the variant. ie variant<vector<int>, int > >. Use which() instead as Ferruccio indicates.

Comment: I tried with `boost::variant<vector<int>, int>` on MSVS 2013 and it worked. What compiler did you try it with? Can you explain your reasons for thinking that it shouldn't work for some cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pointer version of `boost::get`. The [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic) has this example:

```
void times_two( boost::variant< int, std::string > & operand )
{
    if ( int* pi = boost::get<int>( &operand ) )
        *pi *= 2;
    else if ( std::string* pstr = boost::get<std::string>( &operand ) )
        *pstr += *pstr;
}
```

So you use it like you normally would use `boost::get` but pass a pointer to a variant instead, and the result is a pointer which is `nullptr` if that is not the type currently stored in the variant. It's not useful if that type appears more than once in the list of types in the variant, but that is not very common.