# Cast pointer of base class to derived template class without knowing the type

Tags: c++, qt, class, data-structures

I have a tree which is used to store values of different types, e.g. `int`, `double`, `string` or whatever. There is a `Base` class which implements the basic tree functionality (children, parents) and a derived class `template<class T> class Derived: public Base`, where `T` is the type of value to be stored. It has a get function to return the parameters (a template function returning the type `T`)

I am doing a user-interface with `Qt` and thus need to implement a `QAbstractItemModel` in order to view my tree. When subclassing `QAbstractItemModel` I need to be able to call the `get` function of my `Derived` class, but I only have a pointer to an instance of the class (which I get from the `QAbstractItemModel`), and don't know its type, therefore I could cast the pointer to `Base` but this does not allow me to call the `get` function. Is there a way to find the type of my `Derived` class form a `Base` class pointer?

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), please attach some code sample and an explaination of your actual goal.

Comment: No, for all purposes each different instantiation of `Derived<T>` is a different type. As suggested, maybe giving a bit more of context to your problem can help finding a solution.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Qt, but I guess all the items will be presented in a similar way, e.g. as a string or something like that. Maybe you could have a pure virtual method in `Base` called something like `getAsString` (or whatever you need) that returns a common representation of the value, then each subclass can implement it...

Comment: What you seem to want is similar to `boost::variant`, `QVariant` or `std::variant` with ability to learn underlying type. Regarding boost, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344080/boost-variant-how-to-get-currently-held-type?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa suggests you gotta cast and branch yourself. `QVariant` has a `type()` function based on stored type index: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.cpp#n2013. `std::variant` throws on invalid get: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Yes a QVariant would work. Also boost::variant. However, ideally I would have liked to keep dependencies in the backend to a minimum. So this means there is no standard c++ way of doing this?

Comment: would http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid be of help?

Comment: In most cases - what you need from any `Derived<T>` add to `Base` interface (i.e. virtual method). This is wild guessing - because you did not describe your real problem - you described only problem that you have when you wanted to apply your solution to real problem  - this basically means XY problem mentioned in very first comment

Comment: I mean - describe why you need to call ` to call the get function of my Derived class` - what it is for?

Answer (score -1):

Your Tree does not store value of ***different*** type, it stores value of the same type (int, double, carottes, cabages) depending of the template instantiation. 
This is very different from having a Tree of QVariant or of any proxyable object to polymorphic class.

Template spreads along the usage until actual instantiation. You need to create a template class of T deriving from QAbstractItemModel that you will instantiate related to the type of T.

```
template <typename T> class MyCustomItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel;

//...
Tree<Cabagge> MyCabaggeTree;
MyCustomModel<Cabagge> MyCabaggeModel;
```

Comment: If a template is instantiated with different type, the template instance itself is a different type.

Comment: For sure. Isn't it what I am precisely saying ?

Comment: you say: "Your Tree does *not* store value of different type" No, it did!